# Makefile tree for debug/test/release builds with multiple targets

Tags: makefile

Structure:

```
makefile
system/
-> makefile
-> kernel/
-> -> makefile
-> -> src/
-> FutureModules
-> -> makefile
-> -> src/
userland/
-> makefile
-> FutureModules
-> -> makefile
-> -> src/
```

Currently I'm building it with `make system`.

1. I'd like to split it up into Debug/Test/Release builds so that i can do something like `make debug system` or `make -d system` with multiple targets (e.g. `make debug system userland` or something like that).
2. I'd like to change the targets so i can directly build a target instead of building `system` and manually have to add the desired targets in `system/makefile`.

Now in order to achieve this:

1. Do constants get shared between makefiles? So when i do `make system` and i define `CFLAGS += -g -Og` in the root makefile, does the `system/makefile` get the constants from the root makefile?
2. Do constants stay the same in a make session? So when i do `make debug system userland` and have something like `debug: CFLAGS += -g -Og`, do system and userland get the `-g -Og` flags?

---

EDIT: I managed to achieve 2. by using `$(shell find -maxdepth 1 -type d)` and some other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
#Build mode. m=d => Debug | m=t => Test | m=r => release | default => release
ifeq ($(m), d)
    NASBUILD = $(NASDEBUG)
    GASBUILD = $(GASDEBUG)
    CPPBUILD = $(CPPDEBUG)
    CBUILD = $(CDEBUG)
else ifeq ($(m), t)
    NASBUILD = $(NASTEST)
    GASBUILD = $(GASTEST)
    CPPBUILD = $(CPPTEST)
    CBUILD = $(CTEST)
else ifeq ($(m), r)
    NASBUILD = $(NASRELEASE)
    GASBUILD = $(GASRELEASE)
    CPPBUILD = $(CPPRELEASE)
    CBUILD = $(CRELEASE)
else
    NASBUILD = $(NASRELEASE)
    GASBUILD = $(GASRELEASE)
    CPPBUILD = $(CPPRELEASE)
    CBUILD = $(CRELEASE)
endif

export NASBUILD
export GASBUILD
export CPPBUILD
export CBUILD
```

Where xxxBUILD and so on gets added to the corresponding xxxFLAGS.

Comment: Why do you put the `export` lines in every branch? This is a solution, but more elegant solutions may be possible.

Comment: Because i thought i had to export variables after they get assigned.